# C - strncpy usage - segfault

Tags: c, strncpy

```
char *test={"0x11","0x12","0x13","0x00","0x00"};
void change(char* test1, char* test2){
     strncpy(test[3], test1, 4);
     strncpy(test[4], test2, 4);
}

chage("0x55","0x66");
```

I can assign the characters to array element directly. However, it will cause the memory leak. That's why I use `strncpy()` instead.

Please advise if you know how to fix it.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings: `-pedantic -Wall -Werror -std=c11`.

Comment: For some reason test is initialized with an array of strings (char**). I wonder how it even works in the first place.

Comment: I wonder how you don't get syntax errors in many places in the last line (0x66 is a number, not a string, and may be implicitly converted to a certaily invalid pointer)

Comment: Don't try to modify constants.

Comment: @PaulStelian it was a typo. I've updated my question

Comment: @user3815726 Still my answer gives a way to actually fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three two you can get segfault here (one suggestion is to enable compiler warnings - they often pick up "stupid mistakes").

The problem is that `test` is probably misdeclared, it should probably have been:

```
char *test[]={"0x11","0x12","0x13","0x00","0x00"};
```

You initialize a `char*` with an array of `char*` which means that you initialize `test` with the first pointer in that array - which means that `test` will point to the string literal `"0x11"`, so when you use `test[3]` as argument to `strncpy` you will send `1` which is converted to a pointer (probably to address `0x31`). `strncpy` would then try to write to that address which is most probable not allowed. You had nearly a fourth reason here, if you had used `test[5]` you would asked to access beyond the end of the string which is disallowed (you can access `test[4]` becase it's the terminating null of the string).

Even if you fix those problems there is a problem because `test[3]` and `test[4]` are initialized using a string literal. Then `strncpy` would try to modify that string literal which is undefined behavior - the segfault is because `test[3]` and `test[4]` resides in read-only memory (allowing them to be in read-only memory is one reason why modifying string literals is undefined behavior).

What you instead could have done is to make sure that you have writable copies in `test` which is maybe not that straight forward in C. One normal solution is to have a function (that you have to call manually) that sets up `test`, and one that tears it down:

```
void init_test(void) {
    int j;

    for(j=0; j<sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]); j++)
        test[j] = strdup(test[j]);

}

void init_fini(void) {
    int j;

    for(j=0; j<sizeof(test)/sizeof(test[0]); j++)
        free(test[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer gives one good reason (never attempt to modify the **contents** of a string (str(n)cpy does that)).

I'm not even sure you want to represent "characters" as strings, especially as the first declaration doesn't work well (assigning an array of strings to a string).

It will take a lot of work to fix this for sure, but you shall begin by replacing "0x11" by '\x11' (I.E. actually use characters), replace strncpy by mere assignment (true characters are an atomic type which can be assigned directly) and finally change the parameters of the change function to get characters instead of strings.